# PHP mysql update int

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code, it inserts a user_id and a post_id to the table likelist.

This part already works fine.

Now I want to add a "+1" to the table **comments** in the column **likes** wich is an int type, where the post_id equals the one from part 1.

How can I do this?

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //initial query
    $query = "INSERT INTO likelist ( user_id, post_id) VALUES ( :user, :post ) ";

    //Update query
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['user_id'],
        ':post' => $_POST['post_id']


    );

    //execute query
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);


    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add post!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }


    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);




} else {
?>
        <h1>Add Like</h1> 
        <form action="addlike.php" method="post"> 
            User ID:<br /> 
            <input type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="user id" /> 
            <br /><br /> 
            Post ID:<br /> 
            <input type="text" name="post_id" placeholder="post id" /> 
            <br /><br /> 

            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Add Like" /> 
        </form> 
    <?php
}

?>
```

**EDIT**
I only want this to happen when the first part succeeds, this makes sure the like is unique and a user cant like one post multiple times.

Comment: [`UPDATE table SET column_x = column_x +1 WHERE column_y = 'something'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html). 5 seconds on Google...

Comment: where should I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:try

```
$update_sql = "update comments set likes = likes + 1 where post_id = :post_id";
```

Comment: Thanks, where should I add it? I only want this to happen when the first part succeeds, this makes sure the like is unique and a user cant like one post multiple times.

Comment: where you have the success code... setting the param, doing the prepare, etc. again for the new statement

Comment: I added it and it doesnt work, the column "likes" is still 0.